# Is there any gradient boosting package that allows controlling the features set used in each estimator?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I am thinking about a problem in which features comes in batches and in different moments of time/environments.

My current problem set is the following:

Let's say you have n datasets with an arbitrary number of features. Is it possible to set for the boosting optimization to use the first dataset in the first k estimators? And then tell it to use all the features from datasets 1 and 2 from the estimators k to k+p?

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Fun question (+1), what you want is doable in all major packages but it takes a bit of tinkering. Please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Formally speaking no, but we can fake it.

In particular we can make use of capabilities of the `fit` method to continue training an old model. As such we do the following:

1. We make $X_{\text{whole}}$ to store the data from  dataset $X_1$ as well as $X_2$. $X_1$  features are available data at the start of the project. $X_2$ features are unavailable so we explicitly sets them a fixed value (say `42`). It is important that all of them are fixed because in that way: a. they don't covary with any of the known features in $X_1$ and b. any splitting algorithm will ignore them as no splitting can ever result in a reduction to our loss.
2. We train for the first $k$ iterations normally using $X_{\text{whole}}$ such that $X_{\text{whole}} = [X_1 , X_2]$. Our booster up until that iteration uses (by necessity) only information from $X_1$.
3. After $k$ iteration have passed/move to new environment, etc. $X_2$'s feature information are now available. We update our $X_{\text{whole}}$ such that it now holds the relevant $X_1$ features it did before but now $X_2$ contains the newly available information.
4. We train for the rest $k+1$ to whatever total number of iteration we expect using the updated  $X_{\text{whole}}$. The first $k$ trees are preserved doing splits only with information from the features available in $X_1$ but the subsequent tress starting from $k+1$ can using features from $X_1$ or $X_2$ depending on the feature's informativeness.

To my knowledge all three major Python GBM implementations have training continuation capabilities in their `fit` methods. [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/examples/continuation.html), [LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html) and [CatBoost](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-reference_train) suggest that in their documentation. (Links provided, albeit with slightly different ways of achieving this - LightGBM & CatBoost use a `init_model` argument, while XGBoost straight-up retrains an existing booster.)

Comment: That's an interesting solution! Would you consider decreasing the feature weights for $X1$ once $X2$ data is available? This can be controlled in XGBoost with the `feature_weights` argument.

Comment: Thank you! Based on the task at hand, I would not consider it. If anything I would want the booster to still find the best solution even if that means "ignoring" $X_2$
provided features.